# How to install an Android app on my device through macOS using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, installation, apk

After creating the release APK file into my app, I should follow the next lines to install an APK on a device:

1. Connect your Android device to your computer with a USB cable.
2. Enter `cd <app dir>` where `<app dir>` is your application directory.
3. Run flutter install

The problem I find, macOS doesn't recognize my device as external disk. I must do it through https://www.android.com/filetransfer/

Any solution?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have USB-Debugging turned on on your device!

The following allows you to automatically build and start the app in release mode on your device or emulator.

```
flutter run --release
```

The easiest way to install an apk on your device manually is

```
adb install your_apk_file.apk
```